# Unhashable type: 'set' when I draw a network

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to understand why I am getting this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`, when I run this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def my_function(file):
    file = file.explode('Two')

    G = nx.DiGraph()
    nx.add_path(G, file['One'])
    nx.add_path(G, file['Two'])

    nx.draw_networkx(G)
    plt.show()
    return
```

with this dataset:

```
 One                Two
wine       {wine, beer, wine, water}
table    {table, oven, chair, kitchen}
 car        {cars, bike, bike}
```

I am not using `set` (nor `frozenset`), but I think the problem could be in the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you adding the path you can `explode` the dataframe first

```
df = df.assign(Two=df.Two.map(list)).explode('Two')
```